# How to prevent a tikzpicture from creating a spurious blank page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, blank-page

When a `tikzpicture` which is vertically too long for the page, a spurious blank page can be inserted preceding the `tikzpicture`. How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: What about overfull/underfull `\vbox`, e.g., from a very long tabular or other kind of box or a long sequence of headings without text in between?

Comment: Please show us a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) or at least the `log`-file section of the these pages.

Comment: it is impossible to answer the question without more information, what for example is on page 3, perhaps it needs to be on an odd page (such as a chapter heading)

Comment: @Schweinebacke @David Carlisle I've found that a `tikzpicture` being vertically too large is causing the issue. The `tikzpicture` extends beyond page number of the page. When I remove parts of the `tikzpicture` extending over the page, the issue resolves itself. Is there anyway I can keep the `tikzpicture` without removing parts of it or have a spurious page appearing?

Comment: two possibilities come to mind: make latex think the page or the tikzpicture is a different size.  for the page approach, `\enlargethispage` is a candidate.  for making the picture seem smaller, an appropriately placed negative `\vspace` can be tried.

Comment: @aerodokuu Could you add enough information (e.g., sample file with a taylored  tikzpicture) to make the problem reproducible and add your findings about the cause as an (self-)answer? This would make this question useful for other visitors of this site.

Comment: You can scale the `tikzpicture`, e.g., using option `scale` or `\resizebox` (see package `graphicx`) or `\scalebox` (also `graphicx`. But this is another question (see you really should edit the question not only comment to it) and would indeed need a MWE (see link above), if it is not already answered.

Comment: @aerodokuu You may have a look at the `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment: If you enclose the parts of your picture, that are below the lower bound of the page LaTeX will ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by using `\scalebox` around the `tikzpicture`. The parameter for `scalebox` was set to a value which has a magnitude less than 1. It was found through a bit of trial and error that the size of the `tikzpicture` was decreased sufficiently and fit on a single page. The spurious blank page then disappeared.

```
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphics}
    %...
    \scalebox{0.95}{ 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %...
    \end{tikzpicture} }
```